# Android app is working on phone, but doesnt work on tablet

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

```
private final void func5() {
    final Timer tmer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                Random r = new Random();
                rakam = dizi[r.nextInt(5)];
                    if (a >= 0 & a < 5) {
                        sayi1.setText(rakam);
                        sayi_dizi1[a] = sayi1.getText().toString();
                        System.out.println(sayi_dizi1[a]);
                        a++;
                    }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(timer2.getText().toString()));
                    sayi1.setText("");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (a >= 5) {
                    sayi1.setText("");
                        sayi2.setText(rakam);
                        sayi_dizi1[a] = sayi2.getText().toString();
                        System.out.println(sayi_dizi1[a]);
                        a++;
                        b++;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(timer2.getText().toString()));
                    sayi2.setText("");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (b >= 5) {
                    isRunning=false;
                    tmer.cancel();
                    sayi1.setText("");
                    sayi2.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    };
    tmer.schedule(task, 0, Integer.parseInt(timer.getText().toString()));
}
```

When i pressed the button this function is running. This app is working on phone, but doesnt work on tablet. I dont understand. The reason of this maybe there are too many threads. 
My tablet has an old version. (4.4.3 Kitkat). I set up another version on Android Studio emulator. This was the last version. And app worked on emulator.
This situation is why it can be?
This is run output:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
Process: com.example.hafza, PID: 9621
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6669)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1005)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4548)
    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11095)
    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11044)
    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6768)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3850)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
    at com.example.hafza.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:43)
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
    D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 600.00, 976.00) opaque 1 <0x5fee5ce8>
    D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x5fee5ce8>
    D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 600.00, 976.00) opaque 1 <0x5fee5ce8>
    D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x5fee5ce8>
    D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41cfcb20  token=android.os.BinderProxy@41cfc2d0  {com.example.hafza/com.example.hafza.MainActivity}}
    D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING handled : 0 /  android.os.BinderProxy@41cfc2d0
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
    D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x5fee5be8) (w:976 h:600 f:1)
    D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x604a7d78) (w:976 h:600 f:1)
    D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x60484a08) (w:976 h:600 f:1)
    close handle(0x60480d58) (w:976 h:600 f:1)
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 1)
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
    D/ActivityThread: ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 /  android.os.BinderProxy@41cfc2d0
```

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29

buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hafza"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: post your error/stacktrace for better debugging.

Comment: Maybe you are targeting a version that is higher than 4.4.3. Post your gradle too so we can check

Comment: i editted my post. But this app working on phone. I didn't take result like this output.

Comment: you can't set the text on views from a thread.  
`sayi1.setText(rakam);` will throw this exception.  Make sure to use a handler to set the text.

Comment: someActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //set text in here
        }
});

Comment: I tried to do this. But just i see in console. TextView isn't changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use runonUIThread() and syncronized the text changing function with common function.

Answer (score 0):

```
((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
   sayi1.setText("");
  }
 });
```

Do it like this(where mContext = context of that activity that has sayi1 views):

Explanation , you are trying to touch (setText()) the view of main or ui thread from a different thread

Comment: I dont undnerstand this part: 
((Activity) mContext)
I tried to use runOnUiThread but textView isn't changing.

Comment: @Ozge if your textview is in your MainActivity than you have to update your MainActivity's text view ryt? This will take care of that replace activity with your activity name and context with that activity context